# cv2 imshow doesnt open window again after closing and opening again, when used with threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, opencv3.0, opencv

In the sample code below,

```
import cv2
from threading import Thread

class Person_Item_Association(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop = False

    def start_camera(self):
        self.stop =False
        camera_thread = Thread(target=self.start_analysis)
        camera_thread.start()

    def stop_camera(self):
        self.stop = True

    def start_analysis(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while not self.stop:
            ret,image = cap.read()
            cv2.imshow("frame",image)
            cv2.waitKey(1)

        cap.release()
        print("resource released")
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I do the following sequence,
call  obj.start_camera(), obj.stop_camera(), cv2.imshow() opens a window ,
but when i again do obj.start_camera() and obj.stop_camera(), it doesn't open a window.
What is wrong here ?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multiprocessing` module instead of `threading` modeule to mitigate the issue.
But I am still unable to find how to fix this with `threading`.

Take a look at a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651537/python-threading-issue-in-opencv).